# Username as subdomain on laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-3

I've set up a wildcard subdomain *.domain.com & i'm using the following .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* index.php?username=%1 [L]
```

Everything works perfectly.

I want to implement this method in laravel. Mainly I want to have my user's profile displayed when you go to username.domain.com. Any ideas on achieving this?

Comment: I supose you are using Laravel 3 ? Or have you started with laravel 4 ?

Comment: I'm still using Laravel 3.

Comment: **Laravel 4 users:** Scroll past the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is easy. Firstly - do NOT change the `.htaccess` file from the default provided by Laravel. By default all requests to your domain will be routed to your `index.php` file which is exactly what we want.

Then in your `routes.php` file just use a 'before' filter, which filters all requests to your application before anything else is done.

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    // Check if we asked for a user
    $server = explode('.', Request::server('HTTP_HOST'));

    if (count($server) == 3) 
    {
        // We have 3 parts of the domain - therefore a subdomain was requested
        // i.e.  user.domain.com

        // Check if user is valid and has access - i.e. is logged in
        if (Auth::user()->username === $server[0])
        {
            // User is logged in, and has access to this subdomain

            // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE WITH THE USER PROFILE
            echo "your username is ".$server[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // Username is invalid, or user does not have access to this subdomain
            // SHOW ERROR OR WHATEVER YOU WANT
            echo "error - you do not have access to here";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Only 2 parts of domain was requested - therefore no subdomain was requested
        // i.e. domain.com

        // Do nothing here - will just route normally - but you could put logic here if you want
    }
});
```

edit: if you have a country extension (i.e. domain.com.au or domain.com.eu) then you will want to change the count($server) to check for 4, not 3

Comment: Everything works perfectly, but when I access the website using SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM the Auth component always says I'm not logged in. Any ideas?

Comment: Its possible a cookie issue - check this link: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1445

Comment: Epic, thanks a lot. What if other variables are passed to that url? Such as pages, pagination stuff and so?

Comment: It will all route normally based upon your routes, controllers etc

Answer (score 14):

Laravel 4 has this functionality out of the box:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {

    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id) {
        // ...
    });

});
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing)

Comment: Do you know how to setup the DNS for this?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say what the full solution would be in your case, I would start with the SERVER_NAME value from the request (PHP: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) such as:

```
$username = str_replace('.domain.com', '', Request::server('SERVER_NAME'));
```

Make sure you additionally clean/sanitize the username, and from there you can lookup the user from the username. Something like:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
```

Somewhere in the routes file you could conditionally define a route if the SERVER_NAME isn't www.domain.com, or domain.com, though I'm sure others can come up with a much more eloquent way for this part...

Answer (score 0):

ability add subdomains like subdomain *. domain.com should be switched by your hosting provider, in the .htaccess you can not configure support of subdomains

Comment: I contacted the hosting support & everything works. But I need an idea how to implement it in laravel 3.