# How to create subdomain in Laravel dynamically?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, subdomain, hosts

In my Windows/System32/drivers/etc/**hosts**, I have this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   site.dev
127.0.0.1   *.site.dev
```

In my xampp/apache/conf/extra/**httpd-vhost**, I have this:

```
<VirtualHost site.dev>  
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp_7/htdocs/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp_7/htdocs/">
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *.site.dev>  
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp_7/htdocs/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp_7/htdocs/">
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I am going to run http://site.dev/project/public, It is working. I have this route command:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.site.dev'], function($subdomain) {
    return $subdomain;
});
```

If I open http://sub.site.dev/startscript/public/ , I get an error of "This site can’t be reached".

The function of the program is that it can create subdirectories. Example, I have a business website. I can access/create like this.

```
inventory.mybusiness.com
sales.mybusiness.com
ad.mybusiness.com
```

Comment: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/dynamic-subdomain-routing

Comment: read this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401468/username-as-subdomain-on-laravel

Comment: I have tried it, I got "Method filter does not exist."

Comment: May be you need to flush all the artisan cache and refresh it. May be system cache not refreshed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have solved it. I used Acyrlic DNS Proxy from this answer. Checkout the below link you will find the answer.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/dynamic-sub-domain-creation-on-new-user-registration-in-laravel-5-and-wampserver

then the

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.dns.dev'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($account) {
        return $account;
    });
});
```

is now working.

Answer (score 1):

I am using laravel version above 5

```
$appRoutes = function() {
    Route::get('/',function(){
        return view('welcome');
    }); 
};

Route::group(['subdomain' => '{subdomain}.yoursitename.com'], $appRoutes );
```

Place this code in your route file.
But in my case, the laravel app was placed after the root so is used subdomain Route like this

```
   $appRoutes = function() {
        Route::get('/foldername/',function(){
            return view('welcome');
        }); 
    };

 Route::group(['subdomain' => '{subdomain}.yoursitename.com/foldername'], $appRoutes );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to develop a multi-tenancy app, you can use the `TenancyForLaravel` library. It is easy to use and takes care of routes, tenant database etc automatically.

You can find it at https://github.com/stancl/tenancy

Comment: I have created my app using TenancyForLaravel on localhost. it is working fine now but I am curious that how it would behave on live server. I mean, do I need to register subdomains on the hosting for each tenant or laravel will still handle them without doing anything. Also how can I manage custom domains to point to SaaS app instead of subdomains. Can you please guide regarding this.

Comment: @inam I have experience with hosting with AWS only  and not shared hosting, which of them are you using?

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean droplet to host my application.

Comment: Okay, I have not used that but I believe it will be similar to AWS. Each sub-domain is automatically routed by the library. If you visit a customer's sub-domain (doe.example.com), It is automatically routed. That's if library is well configured.

Comment: Okay, but I don't need to set any wildcard character entry in DNS to route any subdomain to my project directory ? and how do you handle custom domains ?

Comment: I set up a wild card (*.example.com) CNAME for my own.