# Laravel and Apache2 - create subdomain for each new registered user

Tags: php, laravel, apache, dns, subdomain

I am working with Laravel 5 and Apache 2.

I would like to prepare simple registration module. Each new user should have own subdomain to log in to system. This subdomain should be created dynamically (on the fly - during registration process).

The main problem is how to make Apache and Laravel code to create that new subdomain?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I checked this answer but it is not working the way that I expected

Comment: I think the trick here is to configure Apache to accept *any* subdomain and have it point at your application. You can then set a database record and then check for subdomains in your routing.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to write that configuration?

Comment: Not off the top of my head unfortunately. But if you look up how to set up wildcard subdomain configuration you should be halfway there. I could write an answer with the routing part but I would guess that's not the primary bit you're after.

Comment: Try [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/apache-wildcard-subdomains-examplecom/) for an example of how to do it. Seems as simple as setting up a `*.yourdomain.com` alias or name. I've not tested it though so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create subdomain in Laravel dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804235/how-to-create-subdomain-in-laravel-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use apache wildcard configuration and according to the subdomain you have to setup project configuration, this will not put the load on your server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias localhost *.host.com #wildcard catch all
    VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/your/workspace/public
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "path/to/your/workspace/public">
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this will not put the load on your server - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you create multiple virtual hosts then it'll lay load on the server you have to use wildcard configuration every subdomain will go to your laravel app and there you can handle request by Request class

Comment: In addition to this, use `Route::domain('{user}.yourdomain.tld')->group(function () { ... });` in your route files. All controller methods inside this group will have another parameter included, which will be the subdomain/username.

Comment: OK, I will check it